# What is the best way to open a vcard (vcf) file from a link in Chrome iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, vcf-vcard, chrome-ios

It seems this is impossible.

Chrome iOS wont open a vcf file as far as I can tell and I've tried many possible solutions.

Mobile Safari will open a vcf with the Add Contact screen but there is no way that I can see that  you can explicitly open a link in mobile Safari from Chrome.

The best solution I can come up with is clicking the link copies it, then opens a popup which tells the user to switch to safari and paste the link in there.